# Python timer doesn't pauses, but keep increasing

Tags: python, time

I am currently trying to make work a timer to keep track of a python program. I tried a lot of different ways of doing it, but none of them works when they are into a while True and called through functions: the timer doesn't pauses when asked.

I gave up after a few hours ad found a github user that published his code to make a timer that can be paused.

Here is the modified code that I use for the timing:

```
from time import time

class Timer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.time_data = []
        self.is_started = False
        self.start_time = None

    def start(self):
        if self.is_started:
            return
        else:
            self.start_time = time()
            self.is_started = True
        
        return self

    def pause(self) -> None:
        elapsed = time() - self.start_time
        self.is_started = False

        self.time_data.append(elapsed)
        
    def resume(self):
        if self.is_started:
            print("Timer is already running")
            return

        self.start_time = (time() - sum(self.time_data)) + 1
        self.is_started = True    
        
    def elapsed(self):
        if self.is_started:
            current_elapsed = time() - self.start_time
            total_elapsed = sum(self.time_data) + current_elapsed
        else:
            total_elapsed = sum(self.time_data)
        return total_elapsed
```

I then tried to test it on a simple program:

```
from timing import Timer

timer = Timer()
timer.start()

sleep(1)

timer.pause()

sleep(2)

print(timer.elapsed()) #should print 1"
timer.resume()

sleep(3)

print(timer.elapsed()) #4"

timer.restart()
timer.pause()
print(timer.elapsed()) #0"
```

This one works well, but then I tried to use While True and functions:

```
from time import sleep
from timing import Timer

timer = Timer()

def start():
    timer.start()

def pause():
    timer.pause()

start()
while True:
    print(timer.elapsed())

    if timer.elapsed() >= 3:
        pause() 
        print("paused!")
    
    sleep(0.25)
```

and there is what it gives me:

```
2.2578864097595215
2.5090396404266357
2.7601206302642822
3.011416435241699
paused!
3.011416435241699
paused!
6.274340391159058
paused!
```

and it goes on, keeping increasing to reach a very high value very fast...

Does someone knows what's the problem there ?

Thanks.

Comment: In `pause`, you are always adding a value relative to the the start_time (`elapsed = time() - self.start_time`) to the list, which is going to increase rapidly.

Comment: Why does `resume()` subtract the sum of `time_data`? Just set the start time to the time that it's resumed. `elapsed()` adds `time_data` back in.

Comment: Every pause keeps attaching time, even if it's already paused.

Comment: Do you really need to keep a list of all the periods when it was running? Why not just use a running total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that implementation is just buggy. Here's something that seems to work:

```
import time


class Timer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_time = None
        self.pause_time = None
        self.elapsed_time = 0

    def start(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.pause_time = None

    def pause(self):
        if self.pause_time is not None:
            raise ValueError("Timer is already paused")
        if self.start_time is None:
            raise ValueError("Timer is not running")
        self.pause_time = time.time()
        self.elapsed_time += self.pause_time - self.start_time
        self.start_time = None

    def resume(self):
        if self.pause_time is None:
            raise ValueError("Timer is not paused")
        self.start()

    def restart(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.elapsed_time = 0

    def elapsed(self):
        if self.start_time is not None:
            return time.time() - self.start_time + self.elapsed_time
        return self.elapsed_time


timer = Timer()
timer.start()
time.sleep(1)
timer.pause()
time.sleep(2)
print(timer.elapsed())  # should print 1"
timer.resume()
time.sleep(3)
print(timer.elapsed())  # 4"
timer.restart()
timer.pause()
print(timer.elapsed())  # 0"
```

Comment: Thank's for your help. I now see the issue in my program :)